# Translate older custom content panes in panels

Tags: 7, panels, i18n-l10n

I am working on a Panel's based multilingual site. After some initial site build (Agile), it was decided that localization should be implemented. i18n to the rescue :-)

I am able to translate everything on the site now, however translating the *custom content panes*, in the Panels is giving me hard times. I have enabled `i18n_panels` module which comes as a sub-module of panels itself. This enabled me to find the custom content panes added earlier from the translate interface and then translate them.

The problem I am facing is with the content panes that were created before enabling the `i18n_panels` module. I am not able to find them in the interface. I am also not able to find a reason for this.
I exported the older content pane and the new content pane, just to check if some settings (some key in the exported code), is used to enable translation. But, I am not able to find anything particular.
It would be great, if anyone helps me to find it. I'd then implement it with an update hook.

I have an option to remove and add all the content panes again, however the number of content panes is quite huge, and I'm on a deadline :(